# How to calculate a rolling mean from a series of dates spanning years?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a CSV file containing stock data spanning 10 years. How do I find the rolling mean of those dates using Pandas? I've tried:

```
pd.rolling_mean(df.resample("1D", fill_method="ffill"), window=3, min_periods=1)
```

that I got from a previous answer. But then I get the error:

```
TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex
```

Why does this happen and what is the correct way to do this?

Here is a bit of the CSV file data:

```
    Date    Open    High    Low     Close   Avg Vol Adj Close
Nov 1, 2012 16.90   19.16   16.86   18.77   27,813,200  18.77
Oct 1, 2012 16.00   16.89   15.65   16.84   23,074,600  16.84
Sep 4, 2012 14.64   16.20   14.59   15.98   21,900,500  15.98
Aug 1, 2012 15.86   16.37   14.59   14.65   17,527,600  14.65
Jul 2, 2012 15.80   16.17   15.23   15.84   15,348,400  15.84
Jun 1, 2012 15.04   15.83   14.81   15.83   14,102,700  15.83
May 1, 2012 15.51   16.00   14.80   15.24   19,935,500  15.24
Apr 2, 2012 15.19   15.70   14.73   15.54   16,640,200  15.54
Mar 1, 2012 14.89   15.61   14.35   15.22   15,408,200  15.22
Feb 1, 2012 15.57   16.31   14.37   14.83   22,020,900  14.83
Jan 3, 2012 16.27   16.39   15.35   15.47   18,167,300  15.47
Dec 1, 2011 16.42   16.46   14.57   16.13   21,943,000  16.13
Nov 1, 2011 14.95   16.50   14.75   15.71   24,382,900  15.71
Oct 3, 2011 13.70   16.79   13.37   15.64   36,438,000  15.64
Sep 1, 2011 13.67   15.40   12.45   13.17   42,743,300  13.17
Aug 1, 2011 13.24   13.98   11.09   13.61   33,473,700  13.61
Jul 1, 2011 15.08   15.95   13.04   13.10   29,550,000  13.10
Jun 1, 2011 16.34   16.43   14.50   15.04   25,772,600  15.04
May 2, 2011 17.79   18.84   15.63   16.55   41,113,700  16.55
Apr 1, 2011 16.83   17.77   16.06   17.70   20,728,700  17.70
Mar 1, 2011 16.46   17.70   15.81   16.68   25,018,300  16.68
Feb 1, 2011 16.33   17.84   16.04   16.40   24,578,700  16.40
Jan 3, 2011 16.81   17.34   15.41   16.12   23,201,900  16.12
Dec 1, 2010 16.00   17.22   16.00   16.63   12,970,200  16.63
Nov 1, 2010 16.50   17.60   15.77   15.82   21,166,800  15.82
Oct 1, 2010 14.19   16.76   14.13   16.49   29,726,500  16.49
Sep 1, 2010 13.20   14.53   13.13   14.17   27,527,400  14.17
Aug 2, 2010 14.01   14.52   12.94   13.11   13,811,800  13.11
Jul 1, 2010 13.99   15.60   13.52   13.88   24,186,600  13.88
Jun 1, 2010 15.31   15.84   13.79   13.84   21,523,300  13.84
May 3, 2010 16.68   16.99   14.63   15.34   26,797,300  15.34
Apr 1, 2010 16.58   19.12   16.22   16.53   33,650,200  16.53
Mar 1, 2010 15.43   16.94   15.40   16.53   21,831,600  16.53
Feb 1, 2010 15.14   15.71   14.48   15.31   21,501,000  15.31
Jan 4, 2010 16.94   17.30   14.90   15.01   24,600,000  15.01
Dec 1, 2009 15.03   16.99   14.85   16.78   18,305,700  16.78
Nov 2, 2009 15.75   16.36   14.80   14.97   20,043,500  14.97
Oct 1, 2009 17.65   18.02   15.74   15.90   25,250,700  15.90
Sep 1, 2009 14.50   17.94   13.97   17.81   36,378,300  17.81
Aug 3, 2009 14.56   15.21   14.30   14.61   28,097,800  14.61
Jul 1, 2009 15.49   17.68   14.22   14.32   36,381,400  14.32
Jun 1, 2009 16.17   16.99   14.55   15.66   19,810,700  15.66
May 1, 2009 14.50   15.84   13.91   15.84   24,369,700  15.84
Apr 1, 2009 12.70   15.39   12.60   14.29   24,663,000  14.29
Mar 2, 2009 12.85   14.14   12.31   12.81   20,620,800  12.81
Feb 2, 2009 11.50   14.00   11.49   13.23   18,837,100  13.23
Jan 2, 2009 12.17   13.56   10.81   11.73   21,408,600  11.73
Dec 1, 2008 11.82   13.57   10.50   12.20   20,089,400  12.20
Nov 3, 2008 12.74   14.89   8.94    11.51   31,084,900  11.51
Oct 1, 2008 17.17   17.31   11.25   12.82   32,771,500  12.82
Sep 2, 2008 19.63   20.82   16.88   17.30   24,333,600  17.30
Aug 1, 2008 20.09   20.82   18.87   19.38   13,981,900  19.38
Jul 1, 2008 20.48   24.80   19.59   19.89   30,010,200  19.89
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to convert the Date column to a Datetime, and then set an index on it:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df = df.set_index("Date")
pd.rolling_mean(df.resample("1D", fill_method="ffill"), window=3, min_periods=1)
```

Output like:

```
Date        Open   High       Low        Close      Avg         Vol
2008-07-01  20.48  24.800000  19.590000  19.890000  30.000000   10.000000
2008-07-02  20.48  24.800000  19.590000  19.890000  30.000000   10.000000
```

Comment: Thank you. I have one other question. When I do `df["Date"]`, it returns a class type. But what I was expecting was an array containing the csv column. How do I get an array from this (I'm trying to plot the dates using matplotlib and one of the functions expects an array)

Comment: Once you've set the index on the dataframe to be the date (`df.set_index("Date")`) you can use `df.index.values` to get a numpy array of the datetimes @templateboy

Comment: Great. Sorry if I'm getting off topic but, I also figure this is an array of strings containing the dates? That poses a problem for me. The plot function expects arrays of integers. Do you know if there's something in Python that helps me interpret date times as integral values?

Comment: `map(int, df.index.values)` should give you an integer representation :)

Comment: Thank you. And do you know how I would plot the rolling mean?

Comment: I think you're getting pretty outside the scope of your original question: feel free to ask another one with the new problems that you're having